# Why is my Android app inserting blank records into MySQL database?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

Currently I am working on developing an app through Android Studio and working on coding the login and registration capabilities. We send newly registered users' info to a MySQL database externally (i.e. not locally) through PHP, and also want to log registered users into the app. At the moment, the Android app is not sending the PHP file the information the user types into the text boxes. I put a tracer into the PHP file and it shows that the values are coming up null.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package android.capstone.registerlogin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.capstone.registerlogin.R.id.etCreateAccEmail;
import static android.capstone.registerlogin.R.id.etCreateAccPassword;
import static android.capstone.registerlogin.R.id.etCreateAccUsername;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText etUserName, etPassWord, etEmail;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);

        etPassWord = (EditText) findViewById(etCreateAccPassword);
        etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(etCreateAccUsername);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(etCreateAccEmail);
        final TextView createAcc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCreateAcc);
        createAcc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /* creating this intent shows where you're starting and
                where you want to go, we want to get the to the create account page
                called RegisterUser.java
                   first line creates the intent
                 */
                Intent createIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateAccount.class);
                //second line makes the intent actually happen .startActivity
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(createIntent);
            }
        });

    }



    public void signup(View v) {
        String UserName = etUserName.getText().toString();
        String PassWord = etPassWord.getText().toString();
        String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();



        Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new SignupActivity(this).execute(UserName, PassWord, Email);
    }


    }
```

Here is my SignupActivity.java:

```
package android.capstone.registerlogin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context context;

    public SignupActivity(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String userName = arg0[0];
        String passWord = arg0[1];
        String eMail = arg0[2];



        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String result;

        try {
            data = "?username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
            data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
            data += "&email=" + URLEncoder.encode(eMail, "UTF-8");



            link = "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~gabschle/signup.php" + data;
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String jsonStr = result;
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed." + jsonStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my CreateAccount.java:

```
package android.capstone.registerlogin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.capstone.registerlogin.R.id.etCreateAccEmail;
import static android.capstone.registerlogin.R.id.etCreateAccPassword;
import static android.capstone.registerlogin.R.id.etCreateAccUsername;

public class CreateAccount extends Activity {


    private EditText etUserName, etPassWord, etEmail;
    private Button mButton;
    //private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);

        etPassWord = (EditText) findViewById(etCreateAccPassword);
        etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(etCreateAccUsername);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(etCreateAccEmail);

        final String UserName = etUserName.getText().toString();
        final String PassWord = etPassWord.getText().toString();
        final String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();


        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreateAccSignUp);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new SignupActivity(CreateAccount.this).execute(UserName, PassWord, Email);


            }

            });
        }




    public void signup(View v) {
        String UserName = etUserName.getText().toString();
        String PassWord = etPassWord.getText().toString();
        String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();



        Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new SignupActivity(this).execute(UserName, PassWord, Email);
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("db.soic.indiana.edu","caps16_team19","capstoneteam19","caps16_team19");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
}


$userName = $_GET['username'];
$passWord = $_GET['password'];
$tDate = $_GET['date'];
$tDate = date('Y-m-d');
$eMail =$_GET['email'];

if($eMail == null) {
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
} else {

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO account (username, password, activated, email) VALUES ('$userName', '$passWord', '$tDate','$eMail')");

if($result == true) {
    echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
}
else{
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Let me know if you need additional files!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: debug is your friend. set a breakpoint in doInBackground and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're getting the values from the text fields before they'are assigned (during `onCreate`).

Change to this:

```
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreateAccSignUp);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String UserName = etUserName.getText().toString();
            String PassWord = etPassWord.getText().toString();
            String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new SignupActivity(CreateAccount.this).execute(UserName, PassWord, Email);
        }
    });
```

ps.: that `context` inside SignupActivity is a memory leak.